# multiple select fields cannot submit form?

Tags: coldfusion, html-select

I have multiple select boxes, one on the left and the other one on the right. There are add and remove buttons so User can add items from the left box to the right box and vice versa remove items from the right box to the left.
Everything works well but when I submit the form, there two boxes does not submit.

This is the javascript:

```
<script language="Javascript">
function SelectMoveRows(SS1,SS2)
{
    var SelID='';
    var SelText='';
    // Move rows from SS1 to SS2 from bottom to top
    for (i=SS1.options.length - 1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (SS1.options[i].selected == true)
        {
            SelID=SS1.options[i].value;
            SelText=SS1.options[i].text;
            var newRow = new Option(SelText,SelID);
            SS2.options[SS2.length]=newRow;
            SS1.options[i]=null;
        }
    }
    SelectSort(SS2);
}
function SelectSort(SelList)
{
    var ID='';
    var Text='';
    for (x=0; x < SelList.length - 1; x++)
    {
        for (y=x + 1; y < SelList.length; y++)
        {
            if (SelList[x].text > SelList[y].text)
            {
                // Swap rows
                ID=SelList[x].value;
                Text=SelList[x].text;
                SelList[x].value=SelList[y].value;
                SelList[x].text=SelList[y].text;
                SelList[y].value=ID;
                SelList[y].text=Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my form:

```
<form name="Example" method="post" action="someactionpage.cfm">
Use the ADD button to move columns that match with your excel file    
from the right pane to the left

                <select name="Features" size="20" MULTIPLE>
                    <option value="MName">Middle Name</option>
                    <option value="Gender">Gender</option>
                    <option value="RaceCode">Race Code</option>
                    <option value="BirthDate">Birthdate</option>
                    <option value="HomeAddr1">Home Address 1</option>
                    <option value="HomeAddr2">Home Address 2</option>
                    <option value="HomeAddr3">Home Address 3</option>
                    <option value="HomeCity">Home City</option>
                    <option value="HomeState">Home State</option>
                    <option value="HomeZip">Home Zip</option>
                    <option value="HomeCountry">Home Country</option>
                    <option value="HomePhone">Home Telephone</option>
                    <option value="HomeFax">Home Fax</option>
                    <option value="HomeCell">Home Cell Phone</option>
                    <option value="HomeEmail">Home Email</option>         
                </select>

                <input type="Button" value="Add >>" style="width:100px" 
      onClick="SelectMoveRows(document.Example.Features,
      document.Example.FeatureCod
      es)">
                <input type="Button" value="<< Remove"    
      style="width:100px" onClick="SelectMoveRows(document.Example.
     FeatureCodes,document.Example.Features)">

                <select name="FeatureCodes" size="20" MULTIPLE>
                    <option value="LName">Last Name</option>
                    <option value="FName">First Name</option>
                </select>

<tr><td><input type="submit" name="SubmitColumn" value="NEXT"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Again, this codes are working just fine. Items move and removed just fine from let to right and vice versa. The problem is when I submit the form I don't get these two form field values. I don't see `form.Features` and `form.FeatureCodes` but I got `form.SubmitColumn` on the actionpage

Comment: That is what is supposed to happen. Per the [HTML specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2): *"... When no options are selected, the control is not successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the server when the form is submitted."* If you want the select list items to be submitted, mark them as `selected`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Leigh mentioned in his comments, we need to make the options in the select boxes to be selected, so that, those values will sent to server. I've made the options in both multiple select boxes to be selected. So now it'll give those values on form submit.

And I've noted that the `SelectSort` function is malfunctioning, so I've modified the code as follows and make it to work. Try the following code. Hope it may solve your needs.

```
<script language="Javascript">
    function SelectMoveRows(SS1,SS2)
    {
        var SelID='';
        var SelText='';
        // Move rows from SS1 to SS2 from bottom to top
        for (i=SS1.options.length - 1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            if (SS1.options[i].selected == true)
            {
                SelID=SS1.options[i].value;
                SelText=SS1.options[i].text;
                var newRow = new Option(SelText,SelID);
                SS2.appendChild(newRow);            
                SS1.options[i]=null;
            }
        }
    }

    function selectall(form){

        var sel1 = form.Features.options;
        var sel2 = form.FeatureCodes.options;

        for (i=0;i<=sel1.length-1;i++){
            sel1[i].selected = true;
        }

        for (j=0;j<=sel2.length-1;j++){
            sel2[j].selected = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="Example" method="post" action="" onsubmit="javascript:selectall(this);">
Use the ADD button to move columns that match with your excel file    
from the right pane to the left

                <select name="Features" size="20" MULTIPLE>
                    <option value="MName">Middle Name</option>
                    <option value="Gender">Gender</option>
                    <option value="RaceCode">Race Code</option>
                    <option value="BirthDate">Birthdate</option>
                    <option value="HomeAddr1">Home Address 1</option>
                    <option value="HomeAddr2">Home Address 2</option>
                    <option value="HomeAddr3">Home Address 3</option>
                    <option value="HomeCity">Home City</option>
                    <option value="HomeState">Home State</option>
                    <option value="HomeZip">Home Zip</option>
                    <option value="HomeCountry">Home Country</option>
                    <option value="HomePhone">Home Telephone</option>
                    <option value="HomeFax">Home Fax</option>
                    <option value="HomeCell">Home Cell Phone</option>
                    <option value="HomeEmail">Home Email</option>         
                </select>

                <input type="Button" value="Add >>" style="width:100px" 
      onClick="SelectMoveRows(document.Example.Features,document.Example.FeatureCodes)">
                <input type="Button" value="<< Remove"    
      style="width:100px" onClick="SelectMoveRows(document.Example.
     FeatureCodes,document.Example.Features)">

                <select name="FeatureCodes" size="20" MULTIPLE>
                    <option value="LName" >Last Name</option>
                    <option value="FName" >First Name</option>
                </select>

<tr><td><input type="submit" name="SubmitColumn" value="NEXT"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Good spot. @user1557856 - Might also consider using jQuery. It not required, but does help simplify common tasks like moving list options, selecting all options, etcetera.

Comment: We can also use jQuery plugins for this selection process, For egs :  http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Lightweight-Multi-select-Combo-Box-Plugin-For-jQuery-SelectListActions/

Comment: Thank you Leigh & thank you Rajesh for the comments and the script. It's working great with your script. Users don't have to highlight the items before submitting the form. Thank you again! I tried your suggestion with jquery but it did not work.